# How does numpy.unravel_index work and is there an implementation in C that we can call?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do some unraveling of a multi-dimensional array in Cython/C++/C, which is essentially similar to the `numpy.unravel_index` function.

The `numpy.unravel_index` takes a vectorized index and a tuple of ints that denote the shape of the unraveled array. E.g.

```
# 4th row, 2nd element denotes the vectorized index 10 in a 5x3 array
(3, 1) = np.unravel_index(10, (5, 3))
```

1. I am wondering what is the general algorithm for numpy unravel_index? Can someone explain the algorithm to do this?
2. and a short-follow-on, is there a way of using the `numpy.unravel_index` or the general `multiarray_math` submodule in C? My guess is not.

Comment: It just a straightforward calculation of where the 10th item occurs in a flattened (5,3) array.  `ravel` is easy, `3*3+1`.  Unravel would be something like `10//3, 10-3*(10//3)`.